# Error in proof that $1 = -1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have created a proof that$ 1 = -1$ but I know that this is impossible. Could someone help me find the flaw in this proof...

$i = \sqrt{-1}$

Given

$i^2 = -1$

Given

$i^4 =  1$

Given
$i^8 =  1$

Given
--------------------------All Common Knowledge Above

$i^4= i^8$

Take sqrt of both sides...

$i^2=i^4$

Take sqrt of both sides...

$i= i^2$

$i=-1$

$i^2= -1$ (sub for $i$)

$-1 \times -1$ (sub for $i^2$)  = $1$

$1=-1$

Thankyou all for helping me. I looked at the other questions and this question is not a duplicate. However, we all have one common error; we forgot +- when taking the square root of i^4 = i^2

Comment: $a^2 = b^2$ does not imply $a = b$.

Comment: The question could use [better formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: We have fairly good intuition about positive numbers. Negative, not so much. Nonreal, less still.  Applying so-called rules of algebra beyond our zone of comfort has to be done very carefully.

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes. Seems like valid question

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think it's a duplicate of the one you linked to, which is about getting $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt b$ wrong. I'm sure this is a duplicate of something, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What people seem to be calling you out for without explanation is that if $a^2 = b^2$, then we can have that $a = \pm b$. We can't know which of $b$ or $-b$ we started with, though.

So when you say that $i^4 = i^8$, then good. You're on the right track. But your next step needs to be that $i^2 = \pm i^4$. You then have no contradiction because one of $i^4$ and $-i^4$ is certainly equal to $i^2$.

I hope this helps you. Always try things like these, even if others call you out for being silly. Before being amazing you have to be a little silly.

Comment: +1 for "Before being amazing you have to be a little silly."

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. The irony is that none of my highschool math teachers knew why it is wrong either. Do you know who else made this famous mistake? Einstein. E = +-MC^2 which demonstrates the existence of negative energy.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical example of the misuse of the "$\sqrt .$" function. You said that $\sqrt{i^4}=i^2$ which is not true since $i^4=1$ and $\sqrt{1}=1$, not $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Can anyonw show me what I did wrong instead of just downvoting me? Does anyone think that $\sqrt{i^4}=i^2$?

Comment: I did not downvote, but $\sqrt{i^4} = i^2$ is certainly *possible* since $i^2 \cdot i^2 = i^4$. The "true" answer would be that $\sqrt{i^4} = \pm i^2$, as the others have pointed out.

Comment: @naslundx That is completely false. The square root function is a *function* mapping positive reals to positive reals. For example, $\sqrt 4 = 2$. The point is that from $x^2=y$, if $y>0$, we can only conclude that $x=\sqrt y$ **OR** $x=-\sqrt y$. However, $\sqrt y$ is still a well defined number that is not one of two numbers.

Comment: There ought to be $i^2$ in the last phrase, I believe.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thank you. Fixed.